# Activity Indicator Not Disabling for CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiactivityindicatorview

I have Collection view forming of 3 cells. I am displaying images on them, however, as fetching the image data from the server takes a few seconds, I use nsuserdefaults and cache.

```
let imagesFromUserDefaults
var dataIsFetched = false

viewDidLoad() {
   let imagesFromUserDefaults = // Data from user defaults
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ACollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ACollectionViewCell

   let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
   activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true

   if dataIsFetched == false {
        activityView.center = CGPointMake( cell.contentView.frame.size.width / 2, cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2) 

        cell.contentView.addSubview(activityView)
        activityView.startAnimating()

        cell.img = // set image - works
   } else {
        // Data is fetched from the Server
        activityView.stopAnimating()

        cell.img = // set image - works
   }

func fetchDataFromServer() {
     // onSuccessResponse: Store into Array

     dataIsFetched = true
     collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

However, after the server data is loaded, even though the images change, the activity indicator doesn't go away. So if cells have the same indexPath.row (as proved by images as well), why doesn't it happen with activity indicator?

---

Also, is it more logical to place this behaviour to CollectionViewCell class? What is the proper way of handling

---

Edit:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if initialLoad {
            count = self.defaults.count
        } else {
            count = self.fetched[0].count
        }

        print("number of cells \(count)")
        if count < 4 {
            return count
        }

        return 0

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

Also you can set `activityView.center = cell.center` for a cleaner code.

Comment: I tried `activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true` but no luck. Edited my question. Unfortunately, I can't accept this answer, this doesn't help :(

Comment: Ok logic to fix such case, u return a cell which got activityIndecator that becomes visible as long as dataIsFetched = false, else should hide this cell

Comment: Do you display your fetched data on collectionview ?

Comment: Yes, on cells. On first load, I show images from cache and then, when it's fetched from the server (dataIsFetched = true), reload the collectionView so the images get modified according to the server data (only if there's any difference with cache img and database img). So the indexPath.rows are same, and it's going to the else function. However, the activityIndicator doesn't stop or get removed :/

Comment: I edited my question and added `numberOfItemsInSection` bit. Also I already did set UIActivityIndicator just above the dataIsFetched check...

Comment: U're setting hidesWhenStopped after dataIsFetched check case is false, but when you reload table you're creating a new instance of activityIndicator, which doesn't care about the previous settings you set when dataIsFetched was false , so you just need to set hidesWhenStopped right after your instance allocation method as above

Comment: I also tried setting them as `let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
        activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
        
        if !dataIsFetched {`.. Same outcome :( .. [Let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109980/discussion-between-senty-and-mortgy).

Answer (score 0):

You know, collect view cells are reusable, the 3 cells displayed in the collection view may share the same cell instance. So every time you call the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, you may get the same cell instance, and you repeatedly add an active indicator to the cell but never remove it. That's not good. Imagine what will you to indicate if an image is fetched with YES/NO, that'll be easy, if the image is fetched, you display YES in the cell, otherwise NO. So the indicator is here to do the same thing, the indicator's YES is animating and NO is not animating, don't get tricked because it's spinning, it's not for tracking the whole fetching process. All you need to do is to add the indicator in the prototype cell, and maintain the states of you images, fetched or not. And update the indicator base on the state:

```
var isImageFetched = yourImagesStates[indexPath.row];
if isImageFetched == true {
    cell.indicator.stopAnimating()
    cell.img = image
} else {
    cell.indicator.startAnimating()
}
```

hope it'll help.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve that through Cell class programatically? I think the problem in my case was I was calling `let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)` each time separately.. But if I have `cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`, I think that would work, won't it? What is the way of creating Activity Indicator programatically that can observe and get triggered from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`  with `cell.activity..`?

Comment: @senty yes, totally, in the cell's `awakeFromNib` method, you add the activity indicator to your cell as a public property, and you can access it from the controller.